# POST data with REQUEST to get SessionToken

Tags: c#, webrequest

I hope that someone can help with an actual example

From various posts I have gotten this far, but I keep getting Bad Request.

Basically what i'm trying to achieve is to login using a AppToken key and then retrieve the SessionToken from the Response. This is the info they posted from their API documentation

- Request (JSON)
- POST /login/application
- Content-Type: application/json
- {"Name":"micros",
  "Key":"longstringasyourpasscodegeneratedfromtheapplication"}

The response looks like this (when using Simple REST Client)

```
<Login xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Tamigo.Services.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><DefaultCompanyId i:nil="true"/><DefaultCompanyName i:nil="true"/><DefaultDepartmentId i:nil="true"/><DefaultDepartmentName/><Email/><EmployeeId i:nil="true"/><ImageUrl i:nil="true"/><MenuId>0</MenuId><Name i:nil="true"/><Password/><Role>Application</Role><SessionToken>e1f35353-08f7-4213-a6b9-251313b36701</SessionToken></Login>
```

And from that Response I need to somehow get the "SessionToken" into a variable to use in the next GET Request.

This is the code I put together so far, which is pieces of code that I could find from other similar questions (which of course didn't fit nicely into my apparently completely unique/never seen before type of request):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace RESTServicesXMLParseExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            try
            {
                var request =
                    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.tamigo.com/login/application");

                var postData = "Name=test";
                postData += "&Key=y3LIZ5u5yR9A7a98ypBdygQyIBrqQwZdfdfZKmgtErQ=";
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

                request.Method = "POST";


                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                //Create the REST Services 'Find by Query' request

                XmlDocument locationsResponse = MakeRequest(responseString);
                ProcessResponse(locationsResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }


        //Submit the HTTP Request and return the XML response
        public static XmlDocument MakeRequest(string requestUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                return (xmlDoc);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                Console.Read();
                return null;
            }
        }

        static public void ProcessResponse(XmlDocument locationsResponse)
        {
            //Create namespace manager
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(locationsResponse.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("rest", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Tamigo.Services.Entities");


            XmlNodeList formattedAddressElements = locationsResponse.SelectNodes("//rest:SessionToken", nsmgr);
            Console.WriteLine("SessionToken");
            foreach (XmlNode SessionToken in formattedAddressElements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(SessionToken.InnerText);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API documentation tells you to send an application/json payload, then you better not ignore that as the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is really something different.

With the below changes I get an 401 Unauthorized because I hope the key and/or name are invalid. So I resolved the Bad Request thing.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.tamigo.com/login/application");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

// create the serializer for the Login class
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Login));
// set our login values
var login = new Login{ Name="test", Key ="y3LIZ5u5yR9A7a98ypBdygQyIBrqQwZdfdfZKmgtErQ=" };

// serialize the Login instance directly to the request stream
ser.WriteObject(request.GetRequestStream(), login);

// handle response
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Here is the small helper class that I used so the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) could do its job:

```
public class Login
{
   public string Name;
   public string Key;
}
```